# Insert automatically the seconds since last insert using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EolDatas]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ByteArray] [varbinary](250) NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CycleTime] [float] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_EolDatas] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EolDatas] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_EolDatas_InsertDate]  
        DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [InsertDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EolDatas] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_EolDatas_CycleTime]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CycleTime]
GO
```

I want to insert the value in ByteArray column using a stored procedure, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EolDatas 
    @byteArray varbinary(250) = NULL,
AS
    DECLARE @insertDate datetime2(7) = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @maxDate datetime2(7) = (SELECT MAX(dbo.EolDatas.InsertDate) 
                                     FROM dbo.EolDatas)
    DECLARE @cycleTime float = DATEDIFF(s, @maxDate, @insertDate)

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    @cycleTime = SELECT MAX(InsertDate) FROM EolDatas;

    INSERT INTO dbo.EolDatas (ByteArray, InsertDate, CycleTime)
    VALUES (@byteArray, @insertDate, @cycleTime)
END
```

When I try to save this procedure I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure EolDatas, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure EolDatas, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near '@cycleTime'

Can you please help me fix this procedure?

I want to call this procedure from my app, to pass the byteArray, and during the insertion of the row, the database must set the value for `InsertDate` and `Cycletime`.

Comment: `@byteArray varbinary(250) = NULL,` - remove the comma. And put your `declare` statements after `begin`.

Comment: `@cycleTime=  Select Max(InsertDate) from EolDatas;`
Should be
`Select @cycleTime = Max(InsertDate) from EolDatas;`

Comment: yes, this fix one issue, still get an eroor to @cycleTime - incorrect syntax

Comment: Actually for your logic, you should comment out the line 
`@cycleTime=  Select Max(InsertDate) from EolDatas;`

Comment: You set `@cycleTime` to `DateDiff(s, @maxDate, @insertDate)` correctly, but after the `set nocount on` statement the line `@cycleTime = select max(insertDate) from EolDatas;` is a syntax error, you didn't `set` it. `set @cycleTime = (select max(InsertDate) from EolDatas);` (or alternatively `select @cycleTime = max(InsertDate from EolDatas;`. But why would you set the @cycleTime to the `DateDiff` (as a float, no less), and then try to overwrite it to a Datetime(2) value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should resolve your issues and show you best practice for an SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EolDatas 
(
    @byteArray varbinary(250) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @insertDate DATETIME2(7) = GETDATE(), @maxDate DATETIME2(7), @cycleTime INT; -- Don't use float unless you need to

    -- Assign a variable using a select
    SELECT @maxDate = MAX(InsertDate) FROM dbo.EolDatas;

    SET @cycleTime = DATEDIFF(s,@maxDate,@insertDate);

    -- This line appears to contradict what has come earlier
    -- @cycleTime=  Select Max(InsertDate) from EolDatas;

    INSERT INTO dbo.EolDatas (ByteArray, InsertDate, CycleTime)
    VALUES (@byteArray, @insertDate, @cycleTime);

    RETURN 0; 
END
GO
```